# Using an external OpenID Connect Identity Provider for WSO2 Store access

Tags: wso2-api-manager, openid-connect

I am setting up an instance of WSO2 API manager, and want to give developers access to the API "store" pages by linking it to my existing OpenID Connect identity server (OpenAM). I've added the OIDC configuration into the store configuration file (**wso2am-2.6.0/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/site/conf/site.json**) with all the details of the authorise, token, userinfo endpoints, etc.

When users click login in the store, it is correctly redirecting them to OpenAM to login, and passing an access token back to the store app. I've also ensured some of the required claims are returned from the userinfo endpoint (like preferred_username). I'm also returning a "groups" claim listing the groups the user should be in "subscriber" for example.

The claims I'm returning from userinfo are:

```
{  
   "address":{  
      "formatted":"My House"
   },
   "given_name":"Danny",
   "family_name":"Developer",
   "name":"Danny Developer",
   "preferred_username":"Danny Developer",
   "groups":[  
      "subscriber"
   ],
   "email":"adam.hatherly@nhs.net",
   "sub":"developer1"
}
```

However, whatever I try with claims and group names, the store still gives the error message "User is not permitted to log in to the Store.". I assume there's something else I need to add in either the access token or userinfo endpoint 
claims list to make the store app accept the user, or some other config in the store or carbon console?

Comment: Are you including the "openid" scope in the request?

Comment: Yep - it is requesting the openid scope. All the oidc calls seem to be working correctly (auth, token, userinfo) - it's just that at the end of the process the store app is saying the user is not permitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for the user login issue is that the user does not have relevant permissions to log in to the store. User needs to have internal/subscriber role assigned to it. Since the user is coming from OpenAM and APIM does not have any information to authorize it, login fails.

For this either you should share the user OpenAM user store with APIM (say a shared LDAP) and assign users with internal/subscriber role or use a custom code to add the user to the APIM user store and assign the role.

Another easiest option is to create a user in APIM side (add a dummy password) with subscriber role. but this is not a suitable solution if you do not know all the users

Comment: That's really useful, I suspected that might be the case, thanks! I'll look into where I might need to add some custom code to do this (pre-creating users or integrating with the back-end LDAP aren't going to be practical in my case).

Comment: There are two places you could add the custom code. either in to the repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/store/jagg/jaggery_oidc_acs.jag file or override oidc module in /modules/oidc/module.xml